# Is a multilevel linear model the right one for my data

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I have the following data structure:

```
ID  Phase  X     Y
1   1      0.21  0.23
1   1      0.24  0.23
1   2      1.03  0.23
1   2      0.89  0.23
2   1      0.51  0.89
2   1      0.45  0.89
2   2      0.12  0.89
2   2      1.10  0.89
... ...    ...   ...
n   n      n     n
```

I want to see if there is a correlation between x of phase and y (predicting Y based on X of each Phase). There is only one observation of Y for each ID, but multiple Phase observations and multiple X observations. Assuming my data fulfils the requirements for a multilevel linear model, would this be the right model to use?

Comment: Your use of Stata is more than fine by me, but irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

An ordinary linear model will provide reasonably efficient regression coefficient estimates.  The standard errors will be far too small, and any tests made off of that model will be anti-conservative as a result.  The cluster sandwich covariance estimator will handle extreme overlap in Y if you have a large number of unique subject IDs.  So replace the ordinary variance-covariance matrix with the robust cluster sandwich estimator and then do the usual things.  In R these steps would work:

```
require(rms)
f <- ols(y ~ phase + x, data=mydata)  # possibly ~ phase * x
g <- robcov(f, mydata$id)
anova(g)
Predict(g)
....
```